# How to add random elements of an array to an ordered list?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of ten elements out of which five are displayed randomly. I want to display these five random elements in an ordered list. The goal is that the list numbers remain constant, unchanged while changing the random elements.

How can I achieve it?

I have tried some of the methods but I cannot figure out where the random elements are stored.

```
     <body>

     <button id="btn" onclick="randomValue()"> Change </button>

     <div id="container">

        <ol id="para"> </ol>

     </div>

     </body>
```

```
    var numbers = [

    "Why was the Happy prince weeping?<br>",
    "Why did the Happy Prince give the ruby?<br>",
    "What is the central idea of the poem 'Good Will'?<br>",
    "What was the ill child asking the mother for?<br>",
    "Why is hasty selling disadvantageous?<br>",
    "How should prudent spending of riches be done?<br>",
    "Who advised Wasserkof to get his fess refunded?<br>",
    "Why did the author refuse to go into Lucia's room?<br>",
    "Give a character sketch of Wasserkopf.<br>",
    "How did the war affect the family of the two boys?<br>"
  ];
```

```
       function getRandom(arr, count) {

        var shuffled = arr.slice(0),
            i = arr.length,
            min = i - count,
            temp, index;

        while (i-- > min) {

            index = Math.floor((i + 1) * Math.random());

            temp = shuffled[index];

            shuffled[index] = shuffled[i];

            shuffled[i] = temp;

        }

        return shuffled.slice(min);

       }
```

```
   function randomValue() {

    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = getRandom(numbers, 5);

   }
```

1. Give a character sketch of Wasserkkopf.

I want the number '1' remains unchanged while changing the question.

Comment: Add a code snippet with your problem

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of what you have tried so far. This will help others understand the problem in a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. You don't need the `<br>` at the end of elements.

```js
var numbers = [
    "Why was the Happy prince weeping?",
    "Why did the Happy Prince give the ruby?",
    "What is the central idea of the poem 'Good Will'?",
    "What was the ill child asking the mother for?",
    "Why is hasty selling disadvantageous?",
    "How should prudent spending of riches be done?",
    "Who advised Wasserkof to get his fess refunded?",
    "Why did the author refuse to go into Lucia's room?",
    "Give a character sketch of Wasserkopf.",
    "How did the war affect the family of the two boys?"
];
let ul = document.getElementById("para");

function randomValue() {
  let copy = [...numbers];
  ul.innerHTML = '';

  for(var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    let ixElement = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = copy[ixElement];
    ul.appendChild(li);
    copy.splice(ixElement, 1);
  }
}

randomValue();
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="randomValue()"> Change </button>
<div id="container">
    <ol id="para"> </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: @TarunRathore if you need any explanation, I'll comment the code.

Comment: Great. If it was helpful to you, please accept/upvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could 1) generate the random indices, 2) sort them, 3) then map them to the array values:

```js
function getRandom(arr, count) {
  let randomIndices = [];
  while (randomIndices.length < count) {
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    if (!randomIndices.includes(randomIndex))
      randomIndices.push(randomIndex);
  }
  randomIndices.sort();
  return randomIndices.map(i => arr[i]);
}

let random = getRandom(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten'], 3);
console.log(random);
```